# Updating nested rows

Tags: mysql, trigger, mariadb

I'm trying with this code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON cityies
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 if NEW.visitors <=> OLD.visitors THEN
set visit_time = now()
END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm getting this error message:

> unknown system variable visit_time

Note: `visit_time` has `DATETIME` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems

PROBLEM #1

The `visit_time` needs to be prefixed with `NEW.`

PROBLEM #2

It needs to be a `BEFORE UPDATE`, not `AFTER UPDATE` because you cannot change values in an `AFTER` trigger.

Your code should read

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger BEFORE UPDATE ON cityies
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.visitors <> OLD.visitors THEN
        SET NEW.visit_time = now();
    END IF;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```